# Combine SQL with an external search

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, lucene.net

In my case SQL for structured data and considering Lucene for text search. 
Yes MSSQL has FullText but Lucene offers some stuff I want. 
For the purpose of the question any external search.

In SQL there is a main table with a PK. 
In SQL there are a number queries that use the main table and number of other tables.

From the external search I will get list of Main.PK to filter by.
That list could be from 1 to to 1 million.

The external search is the most expensive part of the search.  The SQL part is very efficient.  Passing the SQL PK to the external is not really a good  option as I need various data from the SQL query.  The only thing coming back from Lucene is the PK (term) and some times the score.

Is there a best practice?

Options I see are

- where Main.PK in (PK values from external search)
- populate the external search PK values in a #TEMP and join to that
  since some times I need the score this seems best as I can put the
  score in the #temp

In an ideal world there would be a join like this:

```
join exeternalvirtualtable as evt 
  on evt.PK = Main.PK 
 and syntax specific to the external search
```

I get that is asking a lot but is there anything like that in general?
Is there a syntax/API to make an external search look like a table (or view) to MSSQL?
Is there anything like that for MSSQL to Lucene?
This is kind of a start [OLE DB Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709836(v=vs.85).aspx)  and   [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(v=sql.100).aspx)
Ideally a [.NET Framework Data Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08(v=vs.110).aspx) for Lucene that mapped some SQL syntax to Lucene.
The app is .NET in case there is a .NET specific solution.

The product RavenDB combines a structures and unstructured (Lucene) search very fast even if the Lucene return a lot of row so there has to be a way to do this short of putting PK in a #temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a syntax/API to make an external search look like a table (or view) to MSSQL?

You can use [IndexSearcher](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int)) class of Lucene, it will give you a TopDocs object that contain the relevant documents (PKs in your case). Then you can populate a SQL table based on this result.

You will need something like this:

```
    TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, MAX_HITS);
    for (int i = 0; i < topDocs.scoreDocs.length; i++) {
        Document doc = searcher.doc(topDocs.scoreDocs[i].doc);
        String pk = doc.get("PK");
        // Connection to database and executing insertion 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks useful.   But it does not make an external search look like a table.  Still very useful.

Comment: I have added a code fragment. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: It is very helpful.  Still not  virtual table.  It is how to populate a real table.

Comment: Looks like a virtual table was too much to ask for.  This seems like the best approach.    Thanks.   Don't get why the question got a down vote but it would not be fair to delete my question to get the down vote to go away.